# Is there any way to delete rows of a relation table without loading all of them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a relation table:

```
MyTable(ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, Amount)
```

I would like to delete all the row which ID1 = X, ID2 = y and ID3 = 3.

I know that if the table has a simple primary key, I could do that:

```
MyType t = new MyType() {ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, ID3 = 3};
myDbContext.Remove(t);
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And this will delete the row, I don't need to load the entity from the database.

But I don't know if it is possible to do in this case, because it should to delete many rows, not only one.

Could I delete without load the entities or in this case I have to load first and remove all?

Thanks.

Comment: **Entity Framework is not designed for batch DML operations** - you will need to run your own custom SQL `DELETE` query. Use `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF do not support native DML, Bulk operations, ect. Probably it is design conciderations - if you do that, you cannot handle what has been deleted and cannot intercept that process to provide, for example, audit trail. Also there is no way to work with in-memory storage and mocking.

There are lot of extensions which can do that with ease. Some of them are paid, other just limited to several databases.

For example (note, I'm one of the creators): https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore

```cs
myDbContext.Set<MyType>()
   .Where(x => x.Amounnt < 10) // any conditions or any query
   .ToLinqToDB()
   .Delete();
```

Comment: So, this will delete all rows from `MyType` table for which the `Amount` column has a value < 10?

Comment: Yes, I have shown `Amount` field just for example that you have not limited by primary key.

Comment: Thanks. I myself also might want to take a look into `linq2db`.